# Is it possible to include an element inside a foreach and indicate that it should not be repeated in each result?

Tags: php, foreach

I read the rest documentation; and to continue; but it doesn't seem to work with this requirement.

```
<?php  
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach ($colors as $value) {
?><p>TITLE</p><?php
 echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
TITLE
red

TITLE
green

TITLE
blue

TITLE
yellow
```

I thought that with break or continue it would be possible but it seems that it is not what I need or I did not understand it exactly.

I need (including the title inside the foreach to avoid longer code like an if condition):

```
TITLE
red

green

blue

yellow
```

Do you know any correct way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just move `<p>TITLE</p>` *out* of the loop if you didn't want it to be repeated...?

Comment: Because I want to know if what I asked is possible. Because I had a div element which is empty if the arrays are empty, two by the way and each one contains different elements hence the title. If I put it outside, only the title is left without anything else and if I put an if condition it should be like this: if($a || $b ){ if ($a){?><p>title</p><?php foreach(...)...}} and the same for $b is understood?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Are you saying you don't want `TITLE` to appear in the event that `$colors` is not set or is empty? If so, why are you so averse to using a simple `if` to detect that?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But without using an if condition outside the loop, in case this is possible. Because otherwise it would have to result in the same condition after if($a || $b){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with the comments on the question, it's still not clear to me why you wouldn't just gate this all with a simple `if`. If you *insist* on continuing with this design, you can check the `$index` of the current item you're iterating on in the `foreach` loop and if it's the first one, echo `TITLE` along with it:

```
<?php  
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach ($colors as $key=>$value) {
  if ($key === 0) echo "<p>TITLE</p>";
  echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

In my personal opinion, however, it would be *much* more readable if you simply gated the entire block here:

```
<?php  
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

if (count($colors) > 0) {
  echo "<p>TITLE</p>";
  foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're right, I'll do it like this. Thanks a lot!